# Laravel Authentication Problems

Tags: php, mysql, forms, authentication, laravel-4

First off I am fairly new to Laravel.

So I have a form in my header on each page and that is pointing to a POST request. I know that I have the proper user email and password in my mySQL database but when I try to login the 'if(Auth::attempt($userdata))' always fails.

Form:

```
@if(Auth::check())
    <li><a href="{{ URL::to('/') }}">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ URL::to('profile') }}">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ URL::to('logout') }}">Logout</a>
    @else
    <div class="navbar-form navbar-left">
    {{ Form::open(array('url' => '/account/sign-in')) }}
        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Email">
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
        </label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Login</button>
    {{ Form::close() }}
```

POST:

```
Route::post('/account/sign-in', function(){
        $userdata = array(
            'email' => Input::get('email'),
            'password' => Input::get('password')
        );

        if(Auth::attempt($userdata)){
            return 'Success';
        }else{
            return 'Fail';
        }
     });
```

I also have included the $fillable in my User.php model:

```
protected $fillable = array('firstname', 'lastname', 'password', 'email', 'code', 'active');
```

Registration method:

```
public function postCreate(){
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),
        array(
            'firstname' => 'required',
            'lastname' => 'required',
            'email'    => 'required|max:50|email', // make sure the email is an actual email
            'password' => 'required|alphaNum|min:3', // password can only be alphanumeric and has to be greater than 3 characters
            'password_confirmation' => 'required|same:password'
        )
    );

    if($validator->fails()){
        return Redirect::route('account-create')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }else{

        //Activation Code
        $code = str_random(60);

        $user = new User;
        $pass1 = Input::get('password');
        $pass2 = Input::get('password_confirmation');
        $firstname = Input::get('firstname');
        $user->firstname = Input::get('firstname');
        $user->lastname = Input::get('lastname');
        $user->email = Input::get('email');
        $user->code = $code;
        $user->active = 0;
        if($pass1 == $pass2){
        $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('pass1'));
        }else{
            return Redirect::to('register/');
        }
        $user->save();
    }


        if($user){
            //send email
            Mail::send('emails.auth.activate', array('link' =>URL::route('account-activate', $code), 'firstname' => $firstname), function($message) use($user){
                $message->to($user->email, $user->firstname)->subject('Activate your Account');
                });

            return Redirect::to('/')->with('global', 'Your account has been create! We have sent you an email to activate your account');
        }
}
```

Sign in method in UsersController:

```
public function postSignIn(){
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), 
        array(
            'email' => 'required',
            'pasword' => 'required'
        )
    );

    if($validator->fails()){
        return Redirect::to('/')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }else{
        $user = array(
            'active' => 1,
            'email' => Input::get('email'),
            'password' => Input::get('password')
        );


        if(Auth::attempt($user)){
            //Redirect to intended page
            return Redirect::intended('/')->with('global', 'Success!!');
        }else{
            /*return Redirect::to('/')->with('global', 'Failed to login');*/
            return Input::all();
        }
    }
    return Redirect::to('/')->with('global', 'There was a problem signing in. Did you activate?');
}
```

View:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    @if(Auth::check())
    <li><a href="{{ URL::to('/') }}">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ URL::to('profile') }}">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ URL::to('logout') }}">Logout</a></li>
    @else
    <div class="navbar-form navbar-left">
    {{ Form::open(array('url' => '/account/sign-in')) }}
        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Email">
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
        </label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Login</button>
    {{ Form::close() }}
    </div>
    <li><a href="{{ URL::to('account/create') }}">Register</a></li>
    @endif
</ul>
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you properly created the password with `Hash::make()`? `$fillable` has no meaning here, as you are not creating the User.

Comment: What error does it throw??

Comment: It doesn't throw an error it just fails the if statement everytime even though I know the login info I put in corresponds with the data in mysql database

Comment: @user2094178 I posted my registration method in my UsersController, I did do Hash::make() properly I think

Comment: `Hash::make(Input::get('pass1'))` should be `Hash::make(Input::get('password'))`

Comment: @user2094178 why does it not login me in? I used 'Auth::attempt($user)' and when I enter the info, it brings me to the intended page but my if(Auth::check()) statement is not passing. I included my signin method above. Thanks again!

Comment: Remove `'active' => 1,` from `$user` array.

Comment: I did that but it's still not working is it because of my view? I posted the part I think applies above.

Comment: is the problem that I'm missing something in the User.php model?

Comment: Please verify if your password field has at least 60 chars in the database. Did you modify anything in app/auth.php?

Comment: What is it returning currently in the view? Are you receiving the empty `<ul>`?

Comment: Yes my password field has 60 chars in the database. I have not touched the auth.php file. Right now when I sign in, I enter the information that I know is correct and the page essentially refreshes because it brings me back to the "/" route which I want it to but instead of switching the menu content to have Home, Profile, and Logout it has the sign in form and register link. It shouldn't have a login form since I have an if statement with Auth::check() to switch the menu content to Home, Profile, and Logout.

Comment: From your code above you should be seeing the return of `Input::all()` when `Auth::attempt()` fails. Please, if you can, update this post with your current files being it routes, controller, model and view.

Comment: That won't help you on this but I suggest you take a look at Sentry

Comment: @user2094178 I couldn't add all my code above so I added it all to a word doc: https://www.dropbox.com/s/475w03h9xx0bzno/code.docx

Comment: Can't download the file, says it is corrupted. Please try again. Maybe you can zip it.

Comment: @user2094178 ok I compressed the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4pt7lzpjbklrxs2/code.docx.zip

Comment: Your `postSignIn` method at `UsersController` has `'pasword' => 'required'`.

Comment: Ok, if you don't mind I'll convert my last comment to an answer and I ask you please to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your files at dropbox, your `postSignIn` method at `UsersController` has `'pasword' => 'required'`.